# Дату,представленной в секундах от начала эпохи UNIX форматировать в привычный вид

Tags: python, время, datetime

как известно что бы получить дату в секундах в python нужно выполнить след действия:

```
import time
timeNow = time.time()
print(timeNow)
```

Как привести ее к виду: ММ:ЧЧ:Время:ГГ

Comment: Приведите пример строки даты в числах, а то формат `ММ:ЧЧ:Время:ГГ` очень не привычный :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сконвертировать в `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
```

После чего можно вывести либо в формате ISO, либо в любом произвольном формате:

```
>>> d.isoformat()
'2020-05-14T20:37:11.326678'

>>> d.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'20:37:11'
```

Все доступные форматные коды можно посмотреть тут: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior